# Is there a Maximum Length for userPrincipalName in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I am writing an application that is linked to Active Directory, and I need to store the userPrincipalName in a database table, but I do not know how big the field would need to be.

[On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680857(VS.85).aspx), no Length is given, and neither in [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html). Now, before I revert to the DOMAIN\Username that has a defined Length ([sAMAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635(VS.85).aspx) is less than 20 chars, NETBIOS Domain Name is max. 15 chars), I wonder if anyone knows what the limit is either by standard, or by the implementation within both Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 domains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Win2k3 SP2 the longest userPrincipleName it allows me to create is 1013 characters long.

Comment: My testing shows the max length is 1024 (under Windows 2012 R2).

Perhaps you were measuring the length of the account name portion of the upn (before the @domain.com suffix)?

Answer (score 3):

While trying to answer this question for myself today I stumbled across a documented answer.

[2.381 Attribute userPrincipalName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/63f5e067-d1b3-4e6e-9e53-a92953b6005b) defines the userPrincipalName in the following way:

```
 cn: User-Principal-Name
 ldapDisplayName: userPrincipalName
 attributeId: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.656
 attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
 omSyntax: 64
 isSingleValued: TRUE
 schemaIdGuid: 28630ebb-41d5-11d1-a9c1-0000f80367c1
 systemOnly: FALSE
 searchFlags: fATTINDEX
 rangeUpper: 1024
 attributeSecurityGuid: e48d0154-bcf8-11d1-8702-00c04fb96050
 isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet: TRUE
 systemFlags: FLAG_SCHEMA_BASE_OBJECT | FLAG_ATTR_REQ_PARTIAL_SET_MEMBER
```

This specifies the maximum length as 1024 according to the [rangeUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/66e85f4e-6c29-4ea6-82a0-6fe5564dca42) attribute definition.

In this context 1024 means octets (bytes), as opposed to Unicode code points, as `omSyntax: 64` is defined as `String(Unicode)` in [LDAP Representations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/7cda533e-d7a4-4aec-a517-91d02ff4a1aa) and references [RFC 2252 LDAPv3 Attributes 6.10 Directory String](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2252.html#section-6.10) which describes it as the following:

> 6.10. Directory String
>
> ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 DESC 'Directory String' )
>
> A string in this syntax is encoded in the UTF-8 form of ISO 10646 (a
> superset of Unicode).  Servers and clients MUST be prepared to
> receive encodings of arbitrary Unicode characters, including
> characters not presently assigned to any character set.

With UTF-8 being a variable length encoding this means that the maximum string length is however many code points you can UTF-8 encode into 1024 octets (bytes). i.e.: For purely ASCII strings that's 1024 code points, for anything with non-ASCII characters it means something less than 1024 code points.

Answer (score 0):

no it's not possible to change the length of characters in Logon Name of Active directory.